# How to make strcmp function?

Tags: c, string, function, strcmp

I want to make my own `strcmp` function, like the one in C.

```
int my_cmp(const char* str1, const char* str2)  
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; str1[index] != '\0' && str2[index] != '\0'; index++)
        if (str1[index] != str2[index])             
            return (str1[index] - str2[index]);             
    return 0;
}
```

Am I right?
I know that not all the strings have the same length.
I'm not sure about condition of for statement.

Comment: Your function is incorrect when the strings have different length but the sorter one has the same content as the longer one up to that point.

Comment: You need to do a unsigned subtraction. If the strings are unequal lengths they aren't equal.

Comment: If you are doing this as a learning exercise, that is fine. However, please note that strcmp can be very heavily used so standard library implementations tend to be highly optimised - inlined and SIMD operations used to test multiple characters per iteration.

Comment: @InternetAussie: The function also exists in c++ and again has the same semantics. Why change the tag?

Comment: @MikeMB True, but the usual C++ way is to instantiate two `std::string` objects and use the various `<`, `>`, ... operators to compare the strings. `strcmp` is far more relevant to C usage.

Comment: @InternetAussie: So? It still isn't what the OP asked and while it likely doesn't matter to him I wouldn't change the meaning of someone elses question without cause. Btw. I sincerely hope you wouldn't use `std::strings` to implement strcmp (which is what this question is about).

Comment: @MikeMB I would not. See my answer for how I'd implement `strcmp`.

Comment: @InternetAussie `strcmp()` provides a `+/0/-` result, very useful for sorting. C++ `>` with `std::string` provides only a true/false compare - not quite the equivalent.  Still, agree with dropping the C++ tag.  Best to avoid C/C++ tagging unless common idiomatic issue exist.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one of the [Official implemention](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-262/ppc/gen/strcmp.c).

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    for ( ; *s1 == *s2; s1++, s2++)
        if (*s1 == '\0')
            return 0;
    return ((*(unsigned char *)s1 < *(unsigned char *)s2) ? -1 : +1);
 }
```

---

Update:

Problems of your code:

1. your code works fine for string of the same length, the other cases it will false.
2. For [`Extended ASCII`](http://www.asciitable.com/)(range between 128~255), you use `sign char`, so their value would overflow to an negative value, then you may get a wrong value.

**fix version**:

```
int my_cmp(const char* str1, const char* str2)  
{
    int index;
    for (index = 0; str1[index] != '\0' && str2[index] != '\0'; index++)
        if (str1[index] != str2[index])
            return ((*(unsigned char *)str1 < *(unsigned char *)str2) ? -1 : +1);

    // here is the fix code.
    if (str1[index] != '\0') {
        return 1;
    } else if (str2[index] != '\0') {
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The "fixed" version also compares chars instead of unsigned chars.

Comment: Why cast to `unsigned char *`instead of to `char *'?

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom Because otherwise you get the wrong answer when a  char >= 128.

Comment: @MikeMB Thanks, great hint.

Comment: My sincerest apologies - I forgot that returning  " -1,0,1" isn't actually part of the specification for strcmp

Comment: Note: Better to use `size_t index` than `int index` and some compilers will warn about casting away `const`.  Suggest `*(const unsigned char *)str1` ...

Answer (score 0):

the following code snippet shows you how you could implement an "strcmp" function:

```
int myStrCmp (const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    const unsigned char *p1 = (const unsigned char *)s1;
    const unsigned char *p2 = (const unsigned char *)s2;

    while (*p1 != '\0') {
        if (*p2 == '\0') return  1;
        if (*p2 > *p1)   return -1;
        if (*p1 > *p2)   return  1;

        p1++;
        p2++;
    }

    if (*p2 != '\0') return -1;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Am I right? I know that not all the strings have the same length. I'm not sure about condition of for statement.

You are almost right. Your `if` statement

```
if (str1[index] != str2[index])
    return (str1[index] - str2[index]);
```

is basically correct (though the characters should be subtracted as `unsigned char`s), but the `for` loop itself

```
for (index = 0; str1[index] != '\0' && str2[index] != '\0'; index++)
```

is wrong. Specifically the condition:

```
str1[index] != '\0' && str2[index] != '\0'
```

This is wrong because it checks to make sure that *both* characters at the given index are not `'\0'`, rather than *either* character. This can be fixed by replacing `&&` with `||`.

Here's how a seasoned C programmer might write the `strcmp` function (I wrote this :p (EDIT: @chux suggested an improvement)):

```
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    for (; *s1 && (*s1 == *s2); s1++, s2++) {}
    return (unsigned char)(*s1) - (unsigned char)(*s2);
}
```

Comment: Simplification: `*s1 && *s2 && (*s1 == *s2)` --> `*s1 && (*s1 == *s2)` - then again an optimizing compiler _might_ do that for you.  `(unsigned char)(*s1) - (unsigned char)(*s2)` has OF issue on rare machines whose `unsigned char` is the same bit-width as `int`.